# inline-block div with and without text not vertically aligned

Tags: html, css

I have two `div`s side by side. Both have the same size and `display: inline-block`. The only difference between the two is, the first one has some text and the second one is blank.

HTML:

```html
<div>1</div>
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

The first div is lower than the second one.

I am aware of all the possible fixes, like adding some text or a `&nbsp;` to the second div. Adding `vertical-align: top` fixes this as well, of course.

What I want to know is, can someone explain, why a blank div has a different alignment than a div with some text in it?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67XhJ/)

Comment: if you add 2 line of text, you will see the baseline alignment will change

Comment: @Huangism I added a line and the alignment changes. Thank you for this hint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inline-block boxes are, by default vertically aligned such that the baseline of the inline-block box aligns to the baseline of the line box in which it is rendered.

The baseline of an inline-block box with one line of text, is the baseline of that line. More generally, the baseline of an inline-block is the baseline of the last line of text that it contains. But that means that there is no baseline for an inline-block that contains no text.

In such a situation a fall back rule kicks in, and the bottom of the inline-block box is placed on the baseline of its line box.

Comment: This is a nice explanation. Do you have a pointer to some documentation?

Comment: Adrift's answer provides a link to the relevant spec.

Comment: I already looked into that, but haven't grasped it yet. Seems I must give some thought to that.

Comment: The last paragraph at that link is the important one here.

Comment: The aforementioned Adrift's answer has disappeared. Does anyone have that spec link somewhere?

Comment: @bernie - https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align